# How to embed the plot on Bokeh Flask without URL error?

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I am new to Bokeh and HTML, and am working on setting up a graph which would change when the two filters are changed. But, I am getting a URL not found error on a different window when I run the code via FLASK. Below is the input page (first screenshot) and if i click on submit another URL is loading and saying "URL not found" (second screenshot), not sure what I am doing wrong. I need the input and output on the same page and I'd appreciate if anyone's able to guide me. thanks

**first screenshot**

[image]

**second screenshot**

[image]

my app.py code

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.io import show


x=np.random.random(100)
y=np.random.random(100)

f_12 = pd.Series(['f1', 'f2'])
f_12 = f_12.repeat(50)
f_34 = pd.Series(['f3', 'f4'])
f_34 = f_34.repeat(50)

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x
                          ,'y': y
                          ,'filter_12': f_12
                          ,'filter_34': f_34})

f12_list = sample_df['filter_12'].unique().tolist()
f34_list = sample_df['filter_34'].unique().tolist()


def grph(f_12, f_34):
    small_df = sample_df.loc[(sample_df['filter_12'] == f_12) & (sample_df['filter_34'] == f_34)]   
    x = list(small_df['x'])
    y = list(small_df['y'])
    fig=figure(x_axis_label="x",y_axis_label="y")
    hover=HoverTool()
    hover.tooltips = [
            ('X ','@x'),
            ('Y', '@y')]
    hover.mode = 'mouse'
    fig.add_tools(hover)
    par = np.polyfit(x, y, 1, full=True)
    slope=par[0][0]
    intercept=par[0][1]
    y_cal = [slope*i + intercept  for i in x]

    fig.line(x, y_cal, color='red', legend="Line_fit")
    fig.circle(x, y, color='green', legend='A')

    return fig (#edited this from show(fig) to fig)

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
# Index page
@app.route('/viz2')
def index():
    f_12 = request.args.get("f_12")
    if f_12 == None:
        f_12 = "f1"
    f_34 = request.args.get("f_34")
    if f_34 == None:
        f_34 = "f3"
    # Create the plot
    plot = grph(f_12, f_34)
            # Embed plot into HTML via Flask Render
    script, div = components(plot)
    return render_template("view1.html", script=script, div=div, f12_list=f12_list, f34_list=f34_list, f_12=f_12, f_34=f_34)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

my view1.html file

```
<html>
<head>
<link
    href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.1.0.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.1.0.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<H1>Chart</H1>

<form action="/">
<select name="f_12">
    {% for f12 in f12_list %}
        {% if f12 == f_12 %}
            <option selected value="{{ f12 }}">{{ f12 }}</option> 
        {% else %} 
            <option value="{{ f12 }}">{{ f12 }}</option> 
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<select name="f_34">
    {% for f34 in f34_list %}
        {% if f34 == f_34 %}
            <option selected value="{{ f34 }}">{{ f34 }}</option> 
        {% else %} 
            <option value="{{ f34 }}">{{ f34 }}</option> 
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

{{ script|safe }}
{{ div|safe }}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: added the traceback screenshot to the post!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this:

```
return show(fig)
```

But need to be doing this:

```
return fig
```

Comment: thanks. I have edited the code, but now i am getting an "URL not found error"

Comment: The new image is to some URL that is not `/viz2` that's not a bokeh issue

Comment: yes, i dont know exactly why its doing that..was wondering if you could direct on how to setup the multiple input form to display output on same window

Comment: if I change the @app.route('/viz2') to @app.route('/'').  I am getting the picture loaded on the same page. thanks

Comment: sure thing. just wondering if you could direct me to a document/website/link which i can refer to setup this multiple input type form.?

Comment: Sorry that seems like a separate flask/web-dev question, I don't have any immediate expertise to offer.